# Regex matching between last occurence of character and another character

Tags: regex

Hello I'm trying to get the following results from my regex. I need the characters between the last occurrence of `"_"` and a period. I've got this regex `[^_]+$` but its not getting rid of the `".pdf"` at the end.

Desired output

Original string: SalesOrder_359959_929058.pdf
After regex: 929058

Comment: `_([^_.]+)(?:\.[^_]*)?$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
([^_.]+)\.
```

This will match one or more of any character other than `_` or `.` in group 1, followed by a `.`. You then just have to extract group 1 to get the substring you want.

If your regex engine supports lookaheads, you could also use this:

```
[^_.]+(?=\.)
```

This will match one or more of any character other than `_` or `.` so long as it is immediately followed by a `.`, but the `.` itself is not captured.

Of course, both methods could fail if you have multiple `.` in your string. In that case you might use something like this:

```
([^_.]+)\.[^_.]*$
```

Or this:

```
[^_.]+(?=\.[^_.]*$)
```

Comment: yay!! that's the last one listed and it right. The rest of them didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is only another point of view!

I think that if the format is always the same:

letters_numbers_numbers.extension

you can do something like

```
string[] splits = text.Replace(".", "_").Split('_');
return splits[splits.Length - 2];
```

Output:

929058

Answer (score 1):

If your regex engine supports lookahead, you could use this:

```
[^_]+(?=\.)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/rZ9qQ6

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
[^_.]+(?=[^_]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
_([^_\.]+)\..*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking it for "everything that isn't a _ until the end of the string". Something along the lines of: `_([^_.]+)\..*$` This will result in group(1) containing everything between the last _ and a ., but it requires that there be a . and a _.

If you need to allow strings missing . or _, you can use `_?([^_.]+)(\..*)?$`