# regex match last component of url

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a url like this:

```
https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/Swift_Utilities.git
```

I need to match `Swift_Utilities`. In other words everything between the last forward slash and the `.` needs to be matched. All of the other answers dealing with this that I read did not address excluding the characters after the `.`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
[^/]+(?=\.[^.]*$)
```

For more discussion, see [Regex matching between last occurence of character and another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082467/regex-matching-between-last-occurence-of-character-and-another-character)